# How should I use pandas last function on datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am trying to use the `last()` function on a dataframe with a timestamp index :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'timestamp' : ['2022-06-14 16:01:00.292000+00:00', '2022-05-18 05:00:37.843000+00:00', '2022-06-06 00:00:56.134000+00:00'],
        'otherColumn' : ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    })
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')  
df = df.set_index(['timestamp'])
print(df.last('1D'))
```

here is what it returns : `2022-06-06 00:00:56.134000+00:00 C`
I don't understand how it would return the `2022-06-06`, it should return the `2022-06-14` as this is the most recent one ?

Comment: btw. your format looks wrong, should be %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z - I wonder why that code works in the first place, you should have unconverted remains. Or just skip providing a format at all; you have ISO format which is correctly inferred by the parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`last`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.last.html) documentation mentions (although not very explicitly) **that the Index must be sorted**:

> For a DataFrame with a **sorted DatetimeIndex**, this function selects the
> last few rows based on a date offset.

And, indeed, if you look at the [code of `last`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.4.3/pandas/core/generic.py#L8458), the key logic is using `searchsorted`:

```
start = self.index.searchsorted(start_date, side="right")
```

Thus:

```
df.sort_index().last('1D')
```

output:

```
                                 otherColumn
timestamp                                   
2022-06-14 16:01:00.292000+00:00           A
```